# Shairport on Raspberry PI

Tags: shairplay

I followed these steps to install Shairport on Raspbian

http://jtech4you.com/how-to-setup-a-raspberry-pi-airplay-receiver/

and it works fine, except one thing: after a while (the next day), my iPhone does not detect the AirPlay option anymore.

If I connect to Shairport form my PC, using TuneBlade (which has no problem detecting it), this seems to bring it 'back to life' and the iPhone sees it again.

The PI is connected to the network using a WiFi dongle.

Do you have a clue on what's going on and what could be done to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be useful to check the output of shairport. It's best to keep it running in `screen` or `tmux` and to check the output whenever you fail to see it.

I am also running shairport, and sometimes it just crashes, or goes haywire. Hence I have a cron job which restarts shairport every night, which helps.

Also, it might be that the avahi daemon fails to advertise the shairport service. It might also be neccessary to restart avahi, if it fails to function.

These fixes are a bit crude, but it might simply be that the programs themselves are not yet robust enough to run for a long time.